# Display chunk as text in listing environment (knitr)

Tags: latex, knitr, listings

I want to let the chunk itself be displayed as text inside the listings environment. If I enter the chunk inside listings as below it is getting evaluated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
<<>>=
1+1
@
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way that does not include to comment `<<>>=` and `@` out with `%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorporating a literal code chunk is [`knitr` FAQ 8](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md). For this case, use

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<setup, include=FALSE>>=
render_listings()
@

\begin{lstlisting}
\Sexpr{''}<<>>=
1+1
@
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```